# How to use MPI_Barrier with another communicator?

Tags: process, mpi, communicator

I'm a bit of  newbie on MPI programming ( mpich2 fedora ).
I'm writing be cause, i got Dead lock when use MPI_Barrier with another comunicator different to MPI_COMM_WORLD.

I make 2 communicators like this:

MPI_Comm_split (MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, rank, &split_comm);

If i put a MPI_Barrier where all colors can pass, it'll be all right.

But if i put a MPI_Barrier where only color == 1 can pass, i got Dead lock.

How to use MPI_Barrier with another communicator ?
I was also using MPI_Bcast () (with another different communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD) but it wasn't blocked when nobody call MPI_Bcast too. Can one different communicator  to MPI_COMM_WORLD synchronise your own processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could post a code snippet. It's hard to debug a deadlock from your words alone.

At any rate, you pass the communicator you want to block as an argument to MPI_Barrier: 
http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/mpi_barrier.html
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Barrier.html

MPI_Bcast is a blocking function. So, if one or more ranks do not reach the MPI_Bcast call, then you could have a deadlock.

Remember that MPI_COMM_WORLD includes all ranks, even after the MPI_Comm_Split call.

Comment: The statement about `MPI_Bcast` having an implicit barrier is simply not true. The standard allows for any process to exit a collective call as soon as its part in the operation is complete, which allows for optimised implementations. The only exception is `MPI_Barrier` which is **always** globally synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the implicit barrier. You are totally correct. I edited my comment above to remove that bit.